# RVIZ fixed frame velodyne does not exist

Tags: ros, vlp16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use the velodyne drivers in ROS indigo on my Ubuntu VM running inside Virtualbox. I followed the instructions from here http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E. Unfortunately, even after using the vlp16_points.launch and the vlp16 calibration file, I am unable to see the pointcloud in rviz. I get the fixed frame velodyne not found error in rviz. After digging google for a while I decided to use Wireshark to check if I receive the packets. I could not see the UDP packets in Wireshark (launched as superuser) in my Ubuntu VM. But, when I tried doing the same with Windows, I was able to see the UDP packets. In my Ubuntu VM, I could only see TCP and HTTP under IPV4 unlike UDP in Windows. Is it because of the network config in VM? Do I need to change some settings in it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226718/rviz-fixed-frame-velodyne-does-not-exist/) by [krishnaece1505](https://answers.ros.org/users/25947/krishnaece1505/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2016-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no experience with network configuration for a virtual machine, but from the fact that Windows sees the packets and Ubuntu does not, the problem is almost certainly some kind of Virtualbox issue.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0